# Instantiate model from existing model in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-model

What is the preferred way, if any, to instantiate a Backbone model from an existing model, assuming that the model to be instantiated is of a derived type of the existing model?

The case I have in mind arises when dealing with nested models. For instance, let's say I am using `DeepModel` and I define a function on my "parent" model that returns `this.get("childModel")`. Now the child model is likely of type `Backbone.Model` but I would like it to be of type `ChildModel` which extends `Backbone.Model`. I have been doing this by literally copying over the interesting attributes one at a time. Surely there must be a better way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create new instance of the same model by using [Backbone.Model#clone()](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-clone) method or just using `new model.constructor()`.

```
var ChildModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    ...
});

var child = new ChildModel({ key: "value" });

var new_child = child.clone();
```

If we see the source of `clone` method:

```
clone: function() {
    return new this.constructor(this.attributes);
},
```

we can use the same approach to create new instance but with our data

```
var new_child = new child.constructor({ new_key: "new_value" });
```